# Рекомендации по меткам

Tags: sql, php, mysql

Например пользователь лайкает видео. У видео есть метки например: США, война, Сирия.

В MySQL есть таблица меток

```
id | tag
1  | USA
2  | Siria
3  | war
```

После того как пользователь лайкает видео, надо чтобы метки приставились к пользователю и дальше приплюсовывались к нему, если пользователь лайкает еще одно видео, с такими же метками. То есть он лайкнул видео, с меткой США. И в БД надо положить пользователь с id 1  полюбил метку usa 1 раз, если еще раз лайкнет, то уже 2 раза полюбил эту метку.

Как осуществить это, какие таблицы надо сделать ?

Comment: Походу следующим вопросо будет - "Как вывести список видео с меткой USA которые полюбил пользователь с id 1"

-----

Если вы не знаете как создать таблицу в БД с нужными полями, как вы планируете создавать запросы к БД сразу к нескольким таблицам?

Comment: зачем лайкать метки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Первый подход**. Делаем таблицу `user_tags` с полями `user_id` и `tag_id`. Каждый раз, когда пользователь лайкает видео, записываем метки в таблицу:

```
    insert into user_tags (user_id, tag_id) values (user, tag);
```

Когда нужно посчитать, сколько раз пользователь лайкнул ту или иную метку, делаем такой запрос:

```
    select count(user_id) form user_tags where tag_id = 1;
```

Плюс: простая вставка. Минусы: быстро растущая таблица и необходимость использования статистической функции при каждой выборке.

**Второй подход**. Делаем таблицу `user_tags` с полями `user_id`, `tag_id` и `quantity`. Первые два делаем составным ключом. При записи проверяем, есть ли в базе запись с таким ключом. Если есть, то делаем `update`, увеличивая на 1 число в `quantity`. Если нет, делаем `insert`, вставляя в `quantity` 1.

Плюсы: более компактная таблица, простые поиск и выборка. Минус: более сложная логика вставки записей.